# -551 JET_errConsistentTimeMismatch in secedit.sdb

Tags: windows-10

After restoring a Windows restore point I see a repeating set of errors in Application log produced by `ESENT` and SceCli:

- EventID: 517, Data: -551
- EventID: 454, Data: -551
- EventID: 1202, Data: 0x10d9
- EventID: 1005, Data: 0x10d9

Windows is Russian so I would have a hard time translating the messages to English.

This set appears after boot and once in an hour or so.

The first error is this:

> Description: services (920,R,98) Database recovery failed with error -551 because it encountered references to a database, 'C:\WINDOWS\Security\Database\secedit.sdb', which does not match the current set of logs. The database engine will not permit recovery to complete for this instance until the mismatching database is re-instated. If the database is truly no longer available or no longer required, procedures for recovering from this error are available in the Microsoft Knowledge Base or by following the "more information" link at the bottom of this message.

> services (920,R,98) Восстановление базы данных завершено с ошибкой -551, поскольку встретились ссылки на базу данных "C:\WINDOWS\Security\Database\secedit.sdb", не соответствующую текущему набору журналов. Ядро СУБД не позволит завершить восстановление этого экземпляра, пока несоответствие базы данных не будет устранено. Если база данных больше не доступна или не нужна, обратитесь к базе знаний Майкрософт или перейдите по ссылке в нижней части этого сообщения для получения инструкций по исправлению ошибки.

I tried to run `esentutl /p secedit.sdb`. It showed a success message, but the error didn't go away.